# What is the target of sphinxbase?

Tags: cmusphinx

I downloaded the AndroidPocketSphinx package along with `Pocketsphinx` and `Sphinxbase` and built it per the instructions [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/).

It builds and runs fine, but now I am trying to understand how all the components fit together to come with this impressive system.

I examined the `Sphinxbase` directory tree and could not find any **binary** target of which Pocketsphinx and/or AndroidPocketSphinx could reference. That is, I was expecting a `.so`, `.a`, `.dll`, `bin` or *something* like that, but all I could find were source files in various languages.

I am wondering, how can the system build and run so wonderfully if the very base package doesn't produce any library or similar binary target?

What am I missing?

Comment: Binary library is in lib/armeabi/libpocketsphinx_jni.so. It's plugged in from source code. Overall, SO is not the best place to ask questions like this one.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thanks but there is no `lib/armeabi` subdirectory under `Sphinxbase`. I can only find `libs/armeabi` under `AndroidPocketSphinx-master`. Are you saying that `Sphinxbase` is not an independent library and must be owned by some other project in order to produce a binary? Also, what is the best place to ask questions like this one? Thanks.

Comment: In current configuration sphinxbase is compiled as a part of a demo, it is a dependent library indeed. You can include it indepenently too if you need that, you just need to update Android.mk for that. For generic questions on CMUSphinx it's better to ask on CMUSphinx forum: https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/ or on #cmusphinx channel on freenode irc.